# Mikrotik, script

Tags: mikrotik

I have Mikrotik 3.3, I have a dyndns script, which not works, because of this line:

```
/tool fetch mode=http address="checkip.dyndns.org" src-path="/" 
dst-path="/dyndns.checkip.html"[/b]
```

bad-argument name src-path (line 1 column 52)

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

From the Wiki:
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Tools/Fetch

"Fetch is one of the console tools in Mikrotik RouterOS. It is used to `copy` files from any network device to a Mikrotik router via HTTP or FTP. In latest v5 versions it is possible also to upload files to remote locations."

`src-path (string; Default: )`  **`Title of the remote file you need to copy.`**

From what I gather here `src-path` needs to be a **filename**, not just "/". Try to rerun the command and specify a `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

I try it on ROS 6.10. It work.

There some dumb error that I miss to copy, like wrong line continuation, "[/b]" at end or something similar.